# GridView.DataBind() difficulty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to fill a gridview like this:

```
 private void BindGridView(DataTable dTable)
 {
     gridView.DataSource = dTable;
     gridView.DataBind();
 }
```

In the same .cs file, I am using only `gridView.DataBind();`, and it works.
I want to know how the `DataBind()` method refers to the data source?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Once you've set the data source, you don't need to set it again, so you can just call `DataBind` if you want to _re-bind_ the grid.  The grid keeps a reference to the original source,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place where you are calling only `DataBind` method actually not making any difference since the grid view already had `DataSource` and when you call this function it again bind it with the available data source

When you call this line even once in the page

```
gridView.DataSource = dTable;
```

It assigns datasource to the grid view and any subsequent call to `DataBind` method will bind the grid with the same already loaded data.

Comment: what if `gridView.DataSource=null` ?

Comment: If you just write this line `gridView.DataSource=null` it will have no affect but if you call `DataBind` after this line it will reset the grid and will empty it as there is no data.

Answer (score 1):

DataBind() method is used to bind Source to the server Controls.

DataBind() method forces gridview to bind with a particular DataSource.
Since you have already referred your DataSource, and when you are using only DataBind(), it will take the previous DataSource by default, since it is there in the memory.

However, most controls perform bindings automatically. Thus, you don't need to use this method explicitly.

I hope, this is what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

DataBind is only rendering your datasource that's already been loaded into the object.  You can do other binding's in aspx, for example `<span><%#MyClass.RenderSomething()%></span>` but nothing happens unless you instruct it to bind (ie `page.DataBind();` in your cs).

You can define your DataSource in one section of your code and bind it in another is because your defining the source to the control (your GridView) and when DataBind is finally called is when that all gets processed into the output and event's such `RowCreated` get fired.

Answer (score 0):

private void bindGrid(DataTable dTable)
    {
        try
        {

```
            gvSmokingStatus.DataSource = dTable;
            gvSmokingStatus.DataBind();            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;`enter code here`
    }
}
```